# How to get specific data from a functions parameters in php laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am working on a system to send specific emails to different peoples email addresses (using existing code from a colleague of mine). the unique bits of these email addresses are sent to the parameters of the send function (e.g thisbitisunique@something.com). Using the Laravel platform i'm trying to extract that information attach a string prefix and send it on its way. heres the code

```
        private function sendGeneralManagerEmail($data)
        {   
                 // i want to extract the park name from $data
          $data['ParkName'] = $data->$ParkName;
                  // and add it to this prefix and then use it by the Mail
          $emailprefix = $data."@something.com";

            Mail::send('emails.GeneralManager', $data, function($message)
            {
                $message->to($emailprefix, 'General Managers')->subject('[Urgent] Health & Safety Reports');
        });
     }
```

So my question is how do i extract specific information from my parameters using the laravel framework. Im a newbee when it comes to php and laravel. so just some simple suggestion on specific reading would be grand.

Regards Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add 'use' to a closure

```
    private function sendGeneralManagerEmail($data)
    {
            // i want to extract the park name from $data
            $data['ParkName'] = $data->$ParkName;
            // and add it to this prefix and then use it by the Mail
            $emailprefix = $data . "@something.com";

            Mail::send('emails.GeneralManager', $data, function($message) use ($emailprefix) {
                    $message->to($emailprefix, 'General Managers')->subject('[Urgent] Health & Safety Reports');
            });
    }
```

then you can use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) to do what you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was from your that i was able to make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JulianoMartins for showing me the command 'use', heres how i used it for anyone who  has had a similar problem.

As this function is being called from another function in a loop i used $data directly in the mail function rather than declare the variable outside of it and insert it in.

i hope this helps

```
   private function sendGeneralManagerEmail($data)
   {    
        Mail::send('emails.GeneralManager', $data, function($message) use($data)
        {
         $message->to($data['Park']->ParkName.'@myemail.com', 'General Managers')->subject('[Urgent] Health & Safety Reports');
        });
}
```